# Рекурсия вложенности по линиям

Tags: рекурсия, php

есть массив вложенности:

```
Array
```

(

```
[user_id] => 234
[sponsor_id] => 0
[items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 500
                [sponsor_id] => 234
                [items] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [user_id] => 516
                                [sponsor_id] => 500
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [user_id] => 533
                                [sponsor_id] => 500
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 501
                [sponsor_id] => 234
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 502
                [sponsor_id] => 234
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 503
                [sponsor_id] => 234
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 504
                [sponsor_id] => 234
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 505
                [sponsor_id] => 234
                [items] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [user_id] => 506
                                [sponsor_id] => 505
                                [items] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [user_id] => 507
                                                [sponsor_id] => 506
                                                [items] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [user_id] => 508
                                                                [sponsor_id] => 507
...
```

- Овощи

  - картошка

    - топинамбур
  - капуста

    - молодая
    - старая
  - буряк

    - свежий
- Фрукты
- бананы
- яблоки
- груши
- ягоды
- арбуз
- малина

  - по дешевле
  - по дороже

Нужно это все дело пересобрать по линиям. 
Простой пример:

```
[0] - 1 линия
[0] Овощи
[1] Фрукты
[2] ягоды

[1] - 2 линия
[0] - картошка
[1] - капуста
[2] - буряк
[3] - бананы
[4] - яблоки
[5] - груши
[6] - арбуз
[7] - малина

[2] - 3 линия
[0] топинамбур
[1] молодая
[2] старая
[3] свежий
[4] по дешевле
[5] по дороже

  моя попытка, не работает   
function getStructToLine($getStruct, $line = 1, $result = array())
{
    $lineArray = array();

    if($getStruct && is_array($getStruct))
    {
        foreach($getStruct as $user)
        {

            $result[$line][] = $user['user_id'];

            if(isset($user['items']) && $user['items'])
            {
                $line++;
                $result[$line] = $this->getStructToLine($user['items'],$line,$result);
            }
        }

    }

    return $result;
}
```